# Scipy - calculate win probability based on team strength

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, bayesian

I have the following dataframe, where 'strengths_team' hold values for a team strength and 'strengths_opponent' holds his opponent values. There are o total of 20 matches being played.

```
strength_team  strength_opponent  strength_diff
0    30.000000   34.945673    4.945673
1    78.332709   66.968902   11.363807
2    59.179468   53.941551    5.237917
3    38.104159   32.708880    5.395279
4    59.314350   49.704009    9.610341
5    42.622705   51.558636    8.935931
6    37.261146   52.570251   15.309105
7    90.000000   47.107531   42.892469
8    70.981641   72.263020    1.281379
9    67.744474   47.512177   20.232297
10   83.795429   30.449607   53.345822
11   54.289996   52.334208    1.955789
12   37.800674   53.076058   15.275384
13   43.634320   51.693518    8.059198
14   74.825777   58.336456   16.489322
15   85.818659   58.032971   27.785688
16   32.708880   66.968902   34.260022
17   30.000000   59.179468   29.179468
18   53.941551   34.945673   18.995879
19   78.332709   38.104159   40.833455
```

I cannot revert to the features that were used to calculate both strengths and I need to calculate an estimated probability for each of the 20 matches above.

I've came across an article [Learning to Rank the Bayesian Way](https://towardsdatascience.com/learning-to-rank-the-bayesian-way-29af4c61939b), that postulates that I can use some Bayesian inference for that purpose, assuming:

1. that Team (human, Pokemon, search result, recommendation, …) has some strength (skill, relevance, …).
2. If Team 1, with strength s₁, and Player 2, with strength s₂, compete, Team 1 wins with a probability of

[image]

But I don't seem to make this approach work for me..

Which statistical tool can I use to achieve this using `scipy`? And how?

Ideally I would like to end up with probabilities in percentuals.

Comment: There's no principled way of calculating this with the information you have. If you knew which teams won over which other teams, you could use a logistic regression. The linked article starts with a dataset of wins and losses, and uses that to infer a strength score. If you had a similar dataset, you could infer how much the strength score matters to the probability.